# Increase Margin of floated elements

Tags: html, css

I have a `.container` in that there are n number of (`left-block` and `right-block`) div's.

`left-block` is floated left and `right-block` is floated right. 
But I am not getting margin after 1st `left-block` and `right-block` and 2nd `left-block` and `right-block`
here is a demo: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ayiziNa/3/)
[image]

Comment: You can use "margin-top" for politics and business

Comment: add `margin-top` to `right-block` and remove br tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `margin-top` to `.left-block` as well as `.right-block`

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/AcEwayU/1)

```
.left-block {
  float:left;
  border:solid #CCC 1px;
  width:350px;
  height:125px;
  background:transparent;
  clear: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  //position:relative;
}

.right-block {
  float:right;
  border:solid #CCC 1px;
  width:350px;
  height:125px;
  background:transparent;
  clear:right;
  //position:relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

P.S Remove the `<br />` tags, they are not required.

---

The above will add `10px` `margin` to top boxes as well, inorder to get rid of it, use the selectors below.

```
.container > div:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.container > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Alien. I used margin bottom instead of top. But i found that they are not inside my `container div`. adding border to container.

Answer (score 0):

**http://jsbin.com/ayiziNa/7/**

You have to be careful with floated elements because they become `inline` elements - you might want to define them as `inline-block` first, so they are able to maintain margin without causing other problems

Here is the code I applied:

```
.container > div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```